# Does Google Apps have a "Global Contact List"

Tags: google, google-workspace

We recently cut over to using Google Apps for our mail/calendars/docs etc...

One thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to create a Global Address List for the company.

When in Google Apps Mail, the autocomplete in the to/cc/bcc field is aware of all the other users@mydomain.com but in the Mail/Contacts section or the full Contacts Manager app, all I can see are contacts that I've alerady emailed.

Does Google Apps just not provide this "Shared Contact List" functionality ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [Contacts service](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134378).
It isn't available to all types of Apps setups, so you'll have to check on that.

Comment: Thanks Su'. That's what I was looking for and luckily we have the business type setup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one of the apps from the Google Apps Marketplace. Stand alone Google Apps does not provide a global contact sharing feature. I have tried Shared Contacts by floreysoft. It was a bit tricky to setup but has worked just as I wanted it to since.